# List of images with their properties

Tags: ios, swift

My problem:
In my app there are a lot of images. I have a list of categories which user can choose for filtering all images by chosen category. User can't delete/edit these images, and can't add smth in it, so I guess I don't need the Core Data.

So my question is: 
How and where in my project should I store and manage images' names with their properties, so I could use this list with files' names and their properties from any ViewController?

Finally, if you didn't get it: It should look like this:

```
1.Name: "imagename.jpg", Category: "Somecategory")
2.Name: "imagename2.jpg", Category: "Anothercategory")
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could try using dictionaries: 'var images = [String:String]()' and set a key for "name" and a key for "category" like this: images["name"] = "imagename.jpg"
        images["category"] = "Somecategory"

Comment: If they are too many images just store them in a JSON file and load them up with a library such as SwiftyJSON

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sure it should help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store your images under `NSDocuments` with a **susbfolder** , I think you can do it without using **database** and **Core Data** .

Let's think a scenerio for you based on **Model View Controller(MVC)** structure:

You want to store images with an special properties like `NSString *categories` and `NSString *filePath` under `NSFileManager` with a **subfolder** . Encode your object and convert it to `NSData`. You need an **Model** class(it's subclass of `NSObject`)
 that keeps your properties. You need to learn how to save a file to your **Documents** path. [This blog](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/) is very good but it's **Objective C**. This is your **Model** and your **image object**.

Create a **View** that shows your images **UICollectionView** (just an example) and collect them with your **image object**. Modify it how you want!

Create your **Controller** class and do all actions here. Like saving image to path, getting image from path, all `UIButton` actions etc... Add your **View** to this class,decode your `NSData` to **your image object** show it.

This is the logic of an example, you can do it according to your necessities.

The way you should following is saving your image data to `NSDocuments` , search it. I advice you to learn **MVC Stucture**

Hope this give you an idea to start.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I need, because I just don't know where to start from!

Comment: If you need more detail just let me know!